# find out the least upper bound of a set.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $\sup \{r\in \mathbb{Q} : r<b\}=b$, where $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

we try to solve :
Let $S= \{r\in \mathbb{Q} : r<b\}$. From the definition, $S$ is bounded by $b$, $S$ is bounded above. Hence $\sup S$ exists. Now, how we have to prove that sup$S$ is exactly $b$?, please help me.

Comment: You can (for instance) use the decimal expansion of $b$. Or the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The definition of $R$ implies that there are rationals and irrationals between ant two reals. "Definitions are your friends."  And your necessary tools. Use them.

Answer (score 3):

Let $s=\sup S$. As $b$ is an upper bound, certainly $s\le b$.
Assume $s<b$. Then there exists a rational number $q$ with $s<q<b$ (why?). But then $q\in S$ and $s$ fails to be an upper bound, contradiction!